# MVC Add Controller Messed Up

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I went to add a controller to a project I hadn't worked on for a few months and found the option to be messed up.  The only options I'm getting is to a Web 2.0 Controller.  How do I fix this to get the MVC Controller option back?

This is where I select add controller
[image: This is where I select add controller]

Instead of getting the add controller dialog I get this add scaffold dialog
[image: Instead of getting the add controller dialog I get this add scaffold dialog]

I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 with Update 3.  I'm targeting .NET 4.5.  And I'm using MVC 4.

Thanks,

Comment: In Common,on the left, do you see MVC tab?

Comment: No, the only thing under Common is "Web API' and it shows the same list of only Web API templates.

Comment: Try to add MVC to your solution. Right-click Project Name and Manage Nuget Packages... Maybe for some reason it doesn't see the MVC anymore.

Answer (score -2):

Try re-installing Visual Studio. 
That will certainly help :)

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that 'add controller' works fine for other projects.  So I think this issue is with just this project.  I may try re-installing Visual Studio if I can't find a fix.